# Rejecting an Approved document Versus Rejecting a Pending document

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, library, versioning

I have Enterprise Wiki site collection which contains a document library.I have set the following settings for the document library:-

- Require content approval for submitted items? >>> Set to Yes
- Who should see draft items in this document library?  >>> Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)

Now I find that SP will implement these two misleading scenarios:-

1. If user with "Approve" permission reject an **Approved** version, then users with Read permission will get this message when they try to read the document:-

> Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

2. While If user with "Approve" permission reject **Pending** version , then users with Read permission will be able to see the latest approved version of the document.

So I have these two questions:-

1. Why SP is implementing these two different scenarios?
2. Is there a way to force my document library to always display the latest approved version of the document , when rejecting Approved or Pending versions?

Thanks